# between clause for date which is stored in the format of h:i A

Tags: php, mysql

I have stored the date in format of 8:00 AM`(h:i A)`,  I need to add between clause for this like

`select * from table where stored_time between ("8:00 A") and (1:00 PM)`

if any one help me to sort this out the it will be an great help to me.

thanks in advance

Comment: What is the type of `stored_time` column?

Comment: @Salamin its varchar

Comment: @user3775081 You cannot use `BETWEEN` with fields of the `VARCHAR` type. The field has to be an actual time format (`DATETIME` for example). [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between).

Answer (score 3):

If it is a datetime field, and not a string you can do

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE HOUR(stored_time) BETWEEN 8 AND 13
```

Might even work with properly formatted strings but I haven't tried that.

Comment: It may be useful to first convert the `VARCHAR` value into `TIME`with the following: `STR_TO_DATE(stored_time, '%h:%i %p')`

Comment: @JoëlSalamin Yes that would help, thanks for the note